# Is it possible to have second-order collective nouns?

Tags: nouns, grammatical-number, collective-nouns

More out of curiosity than out of need, I was just wondering whether it would be possible to have a ***second-order collective noun*** for something, e.g.:

> *One crow* becomes
>   *Several crows* becomes
>   *A murder of crows* becomes
>   *Several murders of crows* becomes
>   *???*

No harm done if that's the biggest it can get (a plural of a collective noun). But if it's possible to have something on a larger scale than that, then I'd love to be enlightened!

P.S. I'm not even sure that this would be useful in any way, beyond communicating that there really are a **lot** of crows!! So if you can think of **a useful purpose for a second-order collective noun**, it would also be nice to hear that.

Comment: What do you mean by a "collective noun"? Are you talking specifically about the artificial, extremely specific terms for animal groups like "murder of crows" (sometimes called "terms of venery")? Or are you including natural-sounding expressions like "group of", "assembly of", "team of" that aren't just used for particular animal species, but for many other things? It's simple to say "a group of murders of crows".

Comment: I'm not sure that 'collective noun' is well-defined. Is 'staff' a collective noun? 'Government'? Probably. 'Pair'? 'Quartet'? Do two pairs always constitute a quartet if they're together?

Comment: several murders of crows becomes a ***massacre*** of crows I would think.

Comment: And of course several massacres of crows becomes a ***genocide*** of crows.  :-)

Comment: In combinatorics/finite set theory, you have a _set_ of crows, and a __family__ of sets of crows. That is, the members of a family are sets.

Comment: I hope Jim's is the best answer you're going to get, K.

Remember when you said *I'm not even sure that this would be useful in any way*? Guess what comes next?

Of course it would be possible grammatically but in practical terms, how could there be a point?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, consider the Roman military:

- Eight soldiers and two auxiliaries form a [contubernium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contubernium).
- Ten contubernia form a [centuria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centuria#Military).
- Five centuriae form a [cohort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohort_(military_unit)).
- Ten cohorts form a [legion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_legion).

(Numbers may vary across history.)